# how to open jquery popup window through header redirect using php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jquery for popup window. This pop-up window will contain 2 file uploading and other text input tag and finally Submit button.Now If user upload a file from the 1st file upload the action is send to upload.php file then redirects to this page, but the pop is closed.So i want the pop-window to be open after the uploaded file is redirected to this page.So that 2nd file upload is done and so on till the final Submit button is pressed.

I want the popup-window to be open when file is redirected to that page.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could submit your file to an iframe, so page isn't 'refreshed' and your poup will remain opened.

```
<form .. target="myIframe">
  ...
</form>

<iframe id="myIframe" name="myIframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Hope this